# Linux / Silverlight question

Tags: linux, silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I have a PHP script running via crontab on hourly basis under Linux.
This script is basically does some tests against database and returns results,
smth like: table_name, number_of_rows, number_of_duplicates.

Also, I have a Silverlight Dashboard for displaying various data and now I want to include results of the tests.
So, question is: how do I push data from Linux based PHP script to Silverlight client?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are restricted to a Linux server, I assume you are serving the Silverlight app from an Apache site. Is that correct?

Silverlight can use its WebClient class to download any web content, so you could have a PHP page make your results available via HTTP (SOAP, XML, HTML etc).

Comment: Silverlight app is hosted at asp.net web site under IIS 7.5. And I want to push content to silverlight app. My idea is to have relationship like: php from linux sends SOAP to some intermediate WebService. From there(or from another webservice: WCF duplex) push data to Silverlight client... Not sure how to implement that interaction between one webservice and another, say, WCF duplex one. Or maybe there is another easier way...

Comment: Usually easier to pull to the IIS server on a regular basis if you can expose the data. There are simple APS.Net cache expiry tricks to emulate a regular service (without a real service).